# Mac builtin video camera (iSight) stopped working

Tags: mac, laptop, video, macbook, isight

The video camera built in to my Mac laptop seems to have stopped working.  When I bring up Photo Booth, for example, it just shows a video camera icon crossed out.  Similarly for other applications.  Is there any way to tell if it's physically broken or if it's some setting in System Preferences or something?

Comment: Have you rebooted?

Comment: Yes, I should've mentioned that I tried that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend trying the instructions mentioned on the Apple Support site first.

[How to Troubleshoot iSight](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2090?viewlocale=en_US)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the AC Adapter connected? 
If you do, here's a site that may help.
http://knoxious.com/783/apple-isight-camera-always-on-but-not-working/

Comment: The link is not working